# $errors[] not returning

Tags: php, error-handling, return

I am working on building a PHP login and registration system for my website. The coding calls for using $errors[] if form fields are empty and functions to check if the input username exist on the database. I am not recieving any errors, even if I do not put in any information.

**login.php**

```
<?php
include 'cic/initalize.php';

if (user_exists('cassey') === true) {
    echo 'exists';
}
die();

if (empty($_POST) === false) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if (empty($username) === true || empty($password) === true) {
        $errors[] = 'Please provide your username and password.';
    } else if (user_exists($username) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'We can\'t find the username entered, please enter a valid 
        username or register to continue';
        }
}
?>
```

**clients.php (users)**

```
<?php
function user_exists($username) {
    $username = sanitize($username);
    return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT userId FROM clients WHERE 
    username = '$username'"), 0) === 1) ? true : false; 
}
?>
```

**code that calls login.php**

```
 <div class="widget">
      <h2>Login | Register</h2>
 </div><!--End widget class tag-->
 <div class="inside">
    <form action="login.php" method="post">
       <ul id="logIn">
          <li>
            Username:<br/>
            <input type="text" name="username"/>
          </li>
          <li>
            Password:<br/>
            <input type="password" name="password"/>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="register.php">Register</a>
          </li>
       </ul>
    </form>
 </div><!--End inside class tag-->
```

Comment: Please show the code that calls `login.php`

Comment: I know only very basic PHP but aren't you missing an 'else' before 'die()' ?

Comment: Actually, I think the 'die' belongs inside the block.

Comment: @Jon, I have added the coding that calls login.php  Alexandre & Ron, I don't think the die(); is the problem, I have tried that a number of ways all producing the same result... blank pages. I believe the problem is in the query, but I am not sure what I've done wrong.

Comment: You need to add into begin: $errors = Array();

Answer (score 0):

**login.php**:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include 'cic/initalize.php';

if (user_exists('cassey') === true)
    echo 'exists';
else
    die "User does not exist!";

if (isset($_POST['your_submit_button']) && isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']))
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if (strlen($username)==0  || strlen($password)==0)
    {
        $errors[] = 'Please provide your username and password.';
    }
    elseif(user_exists($username) === false)
    {
        $errors[] = 'We can\'t find the username entered, please enter a valid 
        username or register to continue';
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Error: at least one field wasn't set in the form !<br>";
    print_r($_POST);
}
?>
```

Documentation:
[isset](http://php.net/isset)
[empty](http://php.net/empty)
[ini_set](http://php.net/ini_set)
[error_reporting](http://php.net/error_reporting)
[print_r](http://php.net/print_r)

Replace `your_submit_button` with the real name of the submit button in your HTML form.
Using `empty()` is not a good idea since the string "0" is considered empty. What you need to check is if the strings contain at least a character (length not equal to zero).

Comment: This was very helpful, I was able to get a User doesn't exist which is better than a blank page, and I do agree that empty was not the best option (This is my second week studying php) however when inputting an existing user I still recieve a user doesnt exist and when I remove the test code (user_exists('cassey').... I am still receiving blank pages and should be getting the error messages defined.

Comment: I just updated my code above, can you give it a try? Read the documentation links, if necessary.